# Como imprimir o ID selecionado do banco de dados?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Há alguma função pra pegar informações de um ID especifico do meu banco de dados e imprimir com o domf?

Meu código:

```
$id = "30";
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);  
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
```

Pra que exiba as informações que eu preciso colocar o id em `$id = "30";` manualmente. Há algum modo de quando eu estiver na pagina com as informações que eu preciso imprimir ele altere automaticamente esse id pelo da página que estou?

Comment: que signifiva domf? veja na sua pergunta  `e imprimir com o domf?` Sinceramente desconheço esse termo. Mas de qualquer forma seria interessante postar o codigo completo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode enviar o valor do ID através de um GET ou POST.

```
id = $_GET["id"];
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);  
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
```

e o valor do id varia de acordo com o GET: link.com/pagina?id=valor